# Call API in Google Scripts to populate in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to send request to URL, so that it populates in Google Sheets. At this moment the log throws error "Order not found". It's my first time writing script for that request. So far I have:

```
function myFunction() {
  var data = {
            "date":"2021-07-01",
            "reference":"REFERENCE",
            "products":[
              {
               "id":"31565598851174",
               "quantity":15
             },
             {
               "id":"31424655589478",
               "quantity":10
             }
            ]
          }
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
   'contentType': 'application/json',
    // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  var url = "https://stockists.rerootedorganic.co.uk/api/order/?key=example"
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

I think that the problem might be with the syntax in `query`. Any help to identify what I'm doing wrong would be amazing, thank you.

Errors:

```
Execution log
11:45:18 AM Notice  Execution started
11:45:19 AM Info    
{"error":{"message":"Order not found"}}
11:45:19 AM Info    null
11:45:20 AM Info    
{"error":{"message":"Order not found"}}
11:45:20 AM Info    {error={message=Order not found}}
11:45:19 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to take the [tour], if you haven't done so yet. Also take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Voting (when you have sufficient reputation) and accepting answers are always completely optional - but very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Adapt this code

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = 'https://stockists.rerootedorganic.co.uk/api/order/?key=example&date='
  var when = '2021-07-01' // string format
  var data = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+when).getContentText())
  Logger.log(data.order.reference)
  for (var i=0;i<data.order.products.length;i++){
    Logger.log(data.order.products[i].id + ' qty: ' + data.order.products[i].quantity)
  }
}
```

to populate the sheet

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('** Menu **')
    .addItem('request','myFunction')
    .addToUi();
}
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var d = Utilities.formatDate(sh.getRange('B3').getValue(), "GMT+2", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  var url = sh.getRange('B1').getValue() + '?key=' + sh.getRange('B2').getValue() + '&date=' + d
  var data = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())
  for (var i=0;i<data.order.products.length;i++){
    sh.appendRow([data.order.reference,data.order.products[i].id,data.order.products[i].quantity])
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I'm wondering if there is a way to pull data from the spreadsheet to the code, so that it populates with it and send a request?

Comment: I have edited may answer or get a copy from ... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ydqxqdkELkJNPwuFLQ5-oIAzB43KifLJKq4cj_ejctQ/edit?usp=sharing